# "fi" error in sh script

Tags: linux, shell

I have been trying to create a craps game in linux vi and I can't seem to figure it out. I have been having trouble with be able to end my "if" statements with "fi" says its an error.. why is this? I have to generate two random numbers between 1-6 and when they are added you either win, loose, or get a point. any help here?

here is what I have been trying:

```
# craps.sh program inn bash shell
# $RANDOM returns a different random integer at each invocation.
# generate_random_number function which returns sum of
# 2 random number between 1 and 6
generate_random_number()
{
    RANGE=6
    #get 2 random numbers
    number1=$RANDOM
    number2=$RANDOM

    # get it between 1 and 6
    number1=$((($number1%$RANGE)+1))
    number2=$((($number2%$RANGE)+1))

    echo number 1 is $number1
    echo number 2 is $number2

    # add 2 numbers
    sum=$(($number1+$number2))
    echo sum is $sum

    #return the sum
    return $sum

}

# play_game() function invoked whenever user wants to play

play_game(){
    # first throw
    generate_random_number
    sum=$?
    # check if win or lost
    if(($sum==2 || $sum==3 || $sum==12))
    then
        # lost then subtract wager from total amount
        amount=$(($amount-$wager))
        echo You Lost $wager$

    fi
```

Comment: What shell are you running that script with? What's the exact error you get?

Comment: Assuming this is a `bash` script, you seem to be missing a `}` at the end and a space after `if`.  Also consider using `echo` or `printf` in `generate_random_number` instead of `return`.  A function should generally `return` the exit status (if it needs to), not its output.

Comment: You say "sh" script, but "sh" has been used as the executable name for a variety of shells, including Thompson, Bourne, Almquist,  and the Bourne-Again shell. I suspect you mean Bash, which you can check with `echo $SHELL` or `echo $0`. Please clarify and tag appropriately!

Comment: Oh there it is in the header comment - `# craps.sh program inn bash shell`. Please don't hide stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with vi.

You need a space after the "if".

Consider reading a shell programming tutorial.

You should also use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: In Bash (and mksh and ksh93, but not in Zsh), that `if(( ... ))` works fine. Even shellcheck doesn't claim it'd be required.

Answer (score 0):

Note with shell programming, the `return` command is used to convey the **status** of the function, not the **value**. Values are passed around via the stdin and stdout. That means debugging/verbose messages have to be printed on stderr:

```
roll_dice() {
    local range=6
    local sum=0

    # add 2 random numbers
    for i in {1..2}; do
        (( sum += (RANDOM % range) + 1 ))
    done

    # "diagnostic" output to stderr
    echo "sum is $sum" >&2

    # values returned on stdout
    echo "$sum"
}
```

Then you do

```
play_game() {
    # first throw
    # capture the value using command substitution
    sum=$( roll_dice )
```

If you want to discard diagnostic output:

```
    sum=$( roll_dice  2>/dev/null )
```

Notes:

- consistency is the key to readable code: either put the opening brace on a new line or the same line, but not both
- don't use ALLCAPS variable names: leave those as reserved for the shell
- in a bash arithmetic expression, `$` is not required for variables

Answer (score 0):

Since this is `bash`, you're missing a few things off the end of your script.

```
[...]
        amount=$(($amount-$wager))
        echo You Lost $wager$
    fi
# close function
}  
# get a wager
read -p "Enter wager " wager
# validate and call play_game()
((wager>0)) && play_game || echo "Invalid wager: $wager"
```

Here it is on TIO:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNNb9swDL3rVxCJV9goWize2sOAbBiwYhiwrcBuOwWyTdtCbSmQ5BhD29@eUR@OnbY@2BQf@fhIygU37fG4hlLzvbk2Ley1ajTvQUgJBYFgWuw6tobkz9ff3@5/gUY7aGmAQyXqGjVKC5rLSrkciw1q4BaQly2dD6rkVih5TQQNStTc4i5E7@TQFxRcD7J0ITC2gnImejP0oGpKyyf2GF@gHRElbIDccMvepk0z9siAHlL9/W576@11g/Yln/FIsDfb2OTCl598gQIch7CvZJyxpGmaxMO7xCvILjdZdk47B@VnQT4Ky1ZNHW9AGJj4XqH5As0nkbyqCFh2SPN0JSeayykjqvKMbuaOjL6RKGwDbIsO9L7oCkHPjDa07/i/XcN7TLN5m273D1jRVmk/B9I5GHqNXFoDVvkcxhaZj1F5LbSxVFCr0XveXu/c0peYV7ZYPoCoYRQSlIZOGeshUVPXLnSbw9MTBPPDbG6mEVCT0huB0BF4H9UprOalJfXudteaLo9VlnfAezVIe0oKRz/mYF4lPiUWOM35rxrgp6MPcOLRWtAoS6qKpyGyZwAWbhwPxZlGXsHVHlZ39K/pqGgVwTUceCcqmpa/lCXvuuVyWJr6uM/vswwuLmbIDcMLW/2QniHwfYr6Vux4/HjzHw)

Comment: im still getting an unexpected "fi" ending.

Comment: @carah - I provided three lines of overlap. The new lines are from `# close function` to end. I just now pasted the content you provided, and added my new lines, and tested it with `sh craps.sh`, and it works.

Comment: @carah - I popped it into TIO, and added that to my answer. Please look at it and understand it.